# c# place string into an array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

This could be very easy, but how can I place or convert a string into an array?

The code that I have, is the following:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string one;
        string[] two;

        one = "Juan";
        two = {one}; // here is the error

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(two);
    }
}
```

And the error is the following:
***Compiler Error Message: CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'string[]'***

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace this:

```
two = {one}; // here is the error
```

With

```
two = new[] { one };
```

OR

```
two = new string[] { one };
```

The reason you are getting the error is clear from the error message.

See: [Object and Collection Initializers (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx)

Later when you are doing `Response.Write`, you will get `System.String[]` as output, since `two` is an array. I guess you need all array elements separated by some delimiter. You can try:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Join(",", two));
```

Which will produce all the elements in the array separated by comma

Comment: The system is showing the following: `Type expected` in the same line. Thanks for your quick answer.

Comment: @JulianMoreno, try `two = new string[] { one };`

Comment: The system shows the the folowing: `The best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string, string[])' has some invalid arguments`.

Comment: @JulianMoreno, my bad, it should be string `","`, not character `','` updated the answer

Comment: It works! Also The `HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Join(',', two)**)**;` lacks from a parenthesis ")". Thanks for your quick help!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to use initialization syntax for an assignment.  This should work:

```
two = new string[] {one};
```

or just

```
two = new [] {one};
```

since the compiler will infer that you want a `string[]`

I think you'll also be surprised what `Response.Write(two);` produces...

Answer (score 0):

You're using the static initializer syntax to try and add an item to your array. That doesn't work. You can use similar syntax to allocate a new array with the value `one` - `two = new string[] { one };` - or you can allocate the array then add elements through assignment like;

```
    string[] two = new string[10];
    two[0] = one; // assign value one to index 0
```

If you do it like this you have to do some bounds checking for example the following will throw an `IndexOutOfRangeException` at runtime;

```
    string[] two = new string[10];
    int x = 12;
    two[x] = one; // index out of range, must ensure x < two.Length before trying to assign to two[x]
```

Answer (score 0):

That syntax (`{one}`) is only valid if you declare the array variable in the same line. So, this works:

```
string one;

one = "Juan";
string[] two = {one};
```

A more common way to initialize an array, which works in more places, is to use the `new` keyword, and optionally have the type be inferred, e.g.

```
string one;
string[] two;

one = "Juan";
// type is inferrable, since the compiler knows one is a string
two = new[] {one};
// or, explicitly specify the type
two = new string[] {one};
```

I usually declare and initialize on the same line, and use [`var`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) to infer the type, so I'd probably write:

```
var one = "Juan";
var two = new[] { one };
```